# Invalid use of group function - MySQL

Tags: mysql

This error occurs while I run the select query, please advise.

```
Error No : 1111
Error : Invalid use of group function
```

Query:

```
SELECT cm.contactid, cm.firstname, cm.surname, cm.mobile, COUNT( * ) total
FROM sales_master as sm, contact_master as cm
WHERE sm.contactid = cm.contactid 
AND cm.mobile != '' AND orderdate>='2012-12-18' AND orderdate<='2013-03-18' 
GROUP BY sm.contactid 
HAVING COUNT(*) >= 1 
ORDER BY COUNT(*) DESC, cm.firstname ASC
```

Comment: Which mysql version you are using ?

Comment: Go though this link http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3969628/strange-mysql-error-1111-supposedly-worked-before

Comment: the one thing i notices is that you are using group by sm.concatid which you are not selecting in your query. This might be causing problem

Answer (score 1):

Change your query like this. Use join instead of cartisian. If type  of cm.orderdate is DAte than remove DATE() from the below query. And use alias total in GROUP BY and ORDER BY
instead of Count(*) .

```
SELECT
  cm.contactid,
  cm.firstname,
  cm.surname,
  cm.mobile,
  COUNT(cm.contactid)    total
FROM sales_master as sm
  LEFT JOIN contact_master as cm
    ON sm.contactid = cm.contactid
WHERE 
    AND cm.mobile != ''
    AND DATE(cm.orderdate) >= '2012-12-18'
    AND DATE(cm.orderdate) <= '2013-03-18'
GROUP BY cm.contactid
HAVING total >= 1
ORDER BY total DESC, cm.firstname ASC
```

Comment: Hello Raheel..
Thank you for the help

Our query and the your version of the query works perfectly fine on the latest version of the MySQL but when we fire this query at Client's Server (which has older version of MySQL than ours ) it doesn't work..
what do you suggest to run it on older version please?
Client's Server is 1and1 and we are unable to get the MySQL version..

Answer (score 0):

There will be two reason:

1) Version compatibility Problem

2) Your query syntax is not ok,I am sending you the solution of second option.
For Version compatibility Problem you must go to the link mentioned by some one on
comment.
You have to use subquery concept for that.

Modify your query something like that:

```
SELECT  sm.contactid ,cm.contactid as contactid , cm.firstname as firstname, cm.surname as surname , cm.mobile as mobile , COUNT( * ) total
FROM    (
            SELECT  sm.contactid,contactid , firstname,surname ,mobile ,total
            FROM    sales_master as sm, contact_master as cm
            WHERE sm.contactid = cm.contactid 
            AND cm.mobile != '' AND orderdate>='2012-12-18' AND orderdate<='2013-03-18' 
            GROUP BY sm.contactid 
         ) q
GROUP BY sm.contactid HAVING COUNT(*) >= 1 
ORDER BY COUNT(*) DESC, cm.firstname ASC
```

I am not sure that i made exact query or not but concept is some thing like that means
"Subquery"...

Comment: Thank You Rahul,

Our query works in latest version of MySQL but doesnt work on older version that runs on Client's server..
Please advise
this certainly is version compatibility problem..

Comment: which version you are using on local and on server,May you please mentioned it...thanks.

Comment: Local Server : 5.5.23
Client Server : 4.0.27

Comment: thanks for your reply but i follow one link and it is saying that error 1111 is only for using wrong group statement.So the question of version compatibility doesn't arise at all.Initially i was thinking that it may be the case of version compatibility but i was wrong.So plz Follow that link http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/error-messages-server.html